# I have to finetune the below query in Postgres its taking time for fetching the data, can you help Me?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, fine-tuning

```
select to_char(ts."SubmittedDate", 'YYYY-MM') as "monthYear",
       MIN(ts."TimeEntryID") as "TimeEntryID",
       SUM(ts."SpentTime") as "TotalHours",
       MAX(ts."CreatedOn") as "CreatedOn",
       ts."ApplicationID",
       ts."TSTypeCodeID",
       rcv."CodeName" as TSType,
       ts."UserID",
       ts."StatusID",
       st."Status"
from task_management_v1."TimeSheet" ts
   left join task_management_v1."Status" st
      on ts."StatusID" = st."ID"
   left join task_management_v1."RefCodeValue" rcv
      on ts."TSTypeCodeID" = rcv."CodeValueID"
   left join task_management_v1."Users" u
      on ts."ApplicationID" = u."ApplicationID" and ts."UserID" = u."UserID"
where ts."ApplicationID" = 34
  and ts."UserID" in ('YXR4318','KXL5356','BXB0448') 
  and ts."StatusID" in ( 47,44,45,46) 
  and ts."SubmittedDate" > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months' 
group by ts."UserID" , 
         ts."StatusID" , 
         ts."ApplicationID",
         1, 
         st."Status", 
         ts."TSTypeCodeID", 
         TSType
order by 4 desc
limit 25 offset 0;
```

I tried with a CTE, but I am getting duplicates.

Comment: We would need a lot more information to assist. What database are you using? Version? What are the definitions of the tables and indexes? What does the verbose EXPLAIN output show? What's the current duration and what's the expected duration of the operation?

Comment: This question lacks `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.